# How to make a nav-item reach the end of the page

Tags: html, user-interface, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, web-development-server

I am new to Bootstrap and web development but I am trying to reorganize the default navbar that is generated with the execution of a blank asp.net core 2.2 web application.  When this web app is generated there are nav-items that are floated to the left, but in this navbar I want to add another nav-item for log in and place it all the way to the right of the page similar to how many websites place their login links.

I have tried playing around with margins and padding in the container as well as in the navbar.  When I would change the margins for the left and right side of the container it would just shift the entire navbar in one direction either left or right.  I have also opened up and looked at the bootstrap.css in order to see how it works and trying to see if I could find useful information.  I have also tried playing around with the different nav-bar classes.

```
//I tried playing around with margins in my css as such
.container{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

//part of my layout page

<header>
  `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light 
   bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp- 
   page="/Index">RazorPagesDemo</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data- 
   toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria- 
   controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex- 
   sm-row ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp- 
   page="/Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp- 
   page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp- 
   page="/Login">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
   </header>
```

[image: webpage navbar]

Here I would like to make it so that my login nav-item reaches all the way to the right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set style as `position:absolute;right:0` to place it at the right of page:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">RazorPagesDemo</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-
                           page="/Index">Home1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-
                           page="/Privacy">Privacy1</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex" style="position:absolute;right:0">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Login">Login</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your navigation is inside `.container` it will be `max-width: 1140px` wide and centered because of `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`.

Try to use `.container-fluid` or remove container div so it will be full width "from left to right".